# null value HttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, .net, httpcontext

I have problem naer download data from httpContextAccessor

.NET 6 / Visual Studio 2022

Domain auhtentication

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
 var userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Program

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor();
//added
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

error > result: null in userName var

I don't know if something is wrong, but I had a similar design on .net core 3.1 and it worked there

Comment: what does `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` returns? you might get null because you don't have user properly logged in

Comment: @user7313094
IsAuthenticated  return false

Comment: so as I said, this is an authentication issue, you might want to include code for it as well if you unsure why it does not log user in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must Enable windows auhtentication, and disable anonymous auhtentication

Project > Properties > Debug > Open debug launch profiles UI

Check: **Enable windows auhtentication**

Uncheck: Enable anonymous auhtentication

image:

[image]